# Sharing power between components in a Arduino circut

Tags: arduino, parallel

I am trying to power both an ultrasound sensor (HC-05) and an infrared sensor (FC-51) from Arduino's 5V pin, connected in parallel. The circuit is very primitive. When connected separately, both components work properly. But when I connect them both, the HC-05 doesn't give the correct distance reading (pulseIn returns 0).

Here's the schematic (FC-51 looks different, but the pins are the same):

[image]

As I said, if I remove the FC-51 from the circuit, HC-05 immediately starts working as it should.

I tested the voltage in each component, and it is correct (close to 5V). I also measured the total current draw of the whole circuit, and it is 36 mA, well below the limits for Vcc and GND pins.

I tried powering the FC-05 from another power source - in that case, HC-05 works. I also tried powering FC-51 from another I/O pin (HIGH) to GND, I/O (HIGH) pin to I/O pin (LOW), and Vcc to I/O pin (LOW), but in every case, the HC-05 doesn't work.

At this point, I'm out of ideas as to why this setup isn't working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I made another experiment, powering Arduino from a power bank, rather than USB cable from my PC. With a power bank, HC-05 works perfectly... But now FC-51 does not! The standby light turns on, but the proximity light does not when I wave my hand in front of it.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You'll find out very quickly that people on this website _do not_ like Fritzing diagrams. It would actually be more helpful if you utilize our built-in circuit plugin editor.

Comment: So when you have both devices drawing current, the 5V line reads 5V?  Do you have bypass caps on each sensor?

Comment: Tim, yes, the 5V line reads 5V. No, I don't have any caps. Just what you see in the diagram.
KingDuken, sorry, I was not aware of that! I'll use the plugin editor next time. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a software issue? I would not expect power issues with these 2 devices. Try leaving both connected, but disable one device at a time in software. I'm guessing that they'll both work.

Comment: If that doesn't work as 100nF bypass capacitors across the power pins of both sensors.

Comment: Drew - well, the FC-51 doesn't exist in software level yet, I just connected the pins, but didn't program any input reads or anything yet... Just relying on the proximity LED to tell if it's working. So there's really nothing to turn off As for the HC-05, it doesn't have anything in common with the pin reserved for the FC-51... Tim, thanks, but what would the capacitors do here?